# How do I get the name of the script file a Class is called from when it is nested in a dot source call

Tags: powershell

If I have the following (simplified Setup)

class.ps1

```
class Test {
    Test() {
        $MyInvocation | Show-Object
    }

    [void] Call() {
        $MyInvocation | Show-Object
        <# 
           here $MyInvocation.ScriptName, PSCommandPath show main.ps1 NOT 
           util.ps1 even though it is called from Util.ps1 
        #>
    }
}
```

Util.ps1

```
Write-Host "Calling from Util.ps1"
$MyInvocation | Show-Object

Function Test-Util {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Host "Calling from Test-Util in Util.ps1"
    $MyInvocation | Show-Object
}

Function Test-Class {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    write-host "Testing Class Test from Util.ps1"
    $Test = [Test]::new()
    Write-Host "Testing Class.Call() from Util.ps1"
    $Test.Call()
}

Function Test-SubUtilTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Test-SubUtil
}
```

SubUtil.ps1

```
Write-Host "Calling from SubUtil.ps1"
$MyInvocation | Show-Object

Function Test-SubUtil {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Host "Calling from Test-Util in Util.ps1"
    $MyInvocation | Show-Object 

    <# 
        here $MyInvocation.ScriptName, PSCommandPath show Util.ps1 NOT 
        main.ps1 as it is called from Util.ps1 
    #>
}
```

Main.ps1

```
. C:\Users\jenny\Class.ps1
. C:\Users\jenny\Util.ps1
. C:\Users\jenny\SubUtil.ps1

Write-Host "From Main.ps1"
$MyInvocation | Show-Object

write-host "Calling Test-Util from util.ps1"
Test-Util

Write-Host "Calling Test-Class from util.ps1"
Test-Class

write-host "Calling Test-SubUtil from Util.ps1"
Test-SubUtilTest
```

> $Test = [Test]::new()

and

> $Test.Call()

are both executed from util.ps1

yet the $MyInvocation only shows me main.ps1

How do I from either the Constructor of the class or one of its methods determine the ps1 file its calling code originates from when its in this kind of a nested dot source setup

I have tried swapping to & instead of . and I've also tried just moving the dot source of the class.ps1 to the util.ps1 file but it still tells me main.ps1 is the source.

Plus the real class file is a singleton meant to be used across multiple dot sourced util.ps1 files and I'm not sure if I can dot source the same class file in multiple files that are each dot sourced into main.ps1 (not that moving the dot source into the single utility file in this example made a difference)

Finally I'm using Show-Object from the PowerShellCookbook module.

It seems odd that it works for a function based nested call but not for a call to a class

Comment: Your claim that `[Test]::new()` and `$Test.Call()` "are both executed from util.ps1" is inaccurate - they're called from functions whose _definitions_ happen to reside in `util.ps1`, but `util.ps1` is never the caller

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen updated the question with evidence it DOES know that a function called from a nested dot source file DOES understand which file is called as the PSCommandPath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the stack to determine the caller:

```
class Test {
    Test() {
        Get-PSCallStack | Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 1 -ExpandProperty "Location" | Write-Host
    }

    [void] Call() {
        Get-PSCallStack | Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 1 -ExpandProperty "Location" | Write-Host
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mhu deserves full credit and the official answer check mark for giving me the answer. But I figured I'd post my fixed classes with the implemented behavior for anyone else who happens to need to do what I had to

```
Enum LogEntryTypes {
    Information
    Error
    Verbose
    Warning
}
```

Log.psm1

```
Class Log {
    [string] $Name
    hidden [string] $FullPath 

    hidden Log([string] $Name, [string] $Path) { 
        $this.Name = $Name 
        $this.FullPath = (Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath "$($this.Name).log")
    }

    [Log] Start([bool] $Append) {
        if (-not $Append) { remove-item -Path $this.FullPath -Force -Verbose }
        $this.Information("$($this.Name) Logging Started to $($this.FullPath)")
        return $this
    }

    [void] Stop() { $this.Information("$($this.Name) Logging Ended to $($this.FullPath)") }

    Information([string] $Message) { $this.Information($Message,$null) }

    Information([string] $Message, [object] $Data) { $this.Write($Message,$Data,[LogEntryTypes]::Information) }

    Warning([string] $Message) { $this.Warning($Message,$null) }

    Warning([string] $Message, [object] $Data) { $this.Write($Message,$Data,[LogEntryTypes]::Warning) }

    Error([string] $Message) { $this.Error($Message,$null) }

    Error([string] $Message, [object] $Data) { $this.Write($Message,$Data,[LogEntryTypes]::Error) }

    Verbose([string] $Message) { $this.Verbose($Message,$null) }

    Verbose([string] $Message, [object] $Data) { $this.Write($Message,$Data,[LogEntryTypes]::Verbose) }

    [void] hidden Write([string] $Message, [object] $Data, [LogEntryTypes] $EntryType) {
        $Message = $Message -replace '"', '`"'
        "[$($EntryType.ToString().ToUpper())]<$([DateTime]::Now)>:`tMessage->$Message" | Add-Content -Path $this.FullPath
        if ($Data -ne $null) { "[$($EntryType.ToString().ToUpper())]<$([DateTime]::Now)>:`tData->$Data" | Add-Content -Path $this.FullPath }
        "Write-$EntryType `"[$($EntryType.ToString().ToUpper())]<$([DateTime]::Now)>:`tMessage->$Message`"" | Invoke-Expression
        if ($Data -ne $null) { "Write-$EntryType `"[$($EntryType.ToString().ToUpper())]<$([DateTime]::Now)>:`tData->$Data`"" | Invoke-Expression }
    }
}
```

Logger.ps1

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using module ".\Log.psm1"

Class Logger {
    hidden static [Dictionary[String,Log]] $_Logger

    static [string] $Path
    static [bool] $Append

    static Logger() { [Logger]::_Logger = [Dictionary[string,Log]]::new() }

    hidden static [string] GetCallingScriptName() { return ((Get-PSCallStack | Where-Object {$_.Location -notlike "$(((Get-PSCallStack | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Location) -split "\.ps1")[0])*" } | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty "Location") -split "\.ps1")[0] }

    static [Log] Get() { return [Logger]::Get($false) }

    static [Log] Get([bool] $Force) {
        $Name = [Logger]::GetCallingScriptName()
        if ($null -eq [Logger]::_Logger[$Name] -or $Force) { 
            [Logger]::_Logger[$Name] = [Log]::new($Name,[Logger]::Path).Start([Logger]::Append)
        }
        return [Logger]::_Logger[$Name]
    }

    static Setup([string] $Path) { [Logger]::Setup($Path,$true) }

    static Setup([string] $Path, [bool] $Append) {
        [Logger]::Path = $Path
        [Logger]::Append = $Append
    }
}
```

thanks to mhu it's pretty simple I can now use this class from any script file by calling

`[Logger]::Get().<Entry Type Method>()` the Get() either opens the existing log created for the script or creates a new log